# Updating IMemoryCache once an entity has changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `CacheService` that uses `GetOrCreateAsync` to create cache based on a key.  I am caching a photograph entity, which has a `byte[]` property.
This caches fine and is retrieved as expected.  However if the photograph entity is updated, the cache still retains the old entity as you would expect because it has not expired, how can I force an update to the cache upon save of this entity?  Do I remove the existing cached entity and re-add the updated one?

Example of my `FromCacheAsync` method in my `CacheService`

```
    public async Task<T> FromCacheAsync<T>(string entityName, int clientId, Func<Task<T>> function)
    {
        string cacheKey = GetClientCacheKey(entityName, clientId, function);

        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T entry))
        {
            async Task<T> factory(ICacheEntry cacheEntry)
            {
                return await function();
            }
            return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, factory);
        }

        return entry;
    }
```

This is an example of using the caching.

```
      var existingPhotograph = await _cacheService.FromCacheAsync(nameof(_context.Photograph), clientId, async () =>
            await _photographRepository.GetByStaffIdAsync(staff.StaffId));
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to invalidate the cache key, when the entity changes.

That may be a bit tricky, if you directly operate on the DbContext. But since you are using repository pattern, that`s  easier to do.

It boils down to inject the `IMemoryCache` into your repository and invalidate it when a picture is updated.

```
public class PhotographRepository : IPhotograpRepository
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    public PhotographReposiory(IMemoryCache cache, ...)
    {
        _cache = cache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cache));
    }

    public async Task Update(PhotographEntity entity)
    {
        // update your entity here
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // this invalidates your memory cache. Next call to _cache.TryGetValue
        // results in a cache miss and the new entity is fetched from the database
        _cache.Remove(GetClientCacheKey(entityName, clientId));
    }
}
```

### Using with Decorator pattern

```
public class PhotographRepository : IPhotograpRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public PhotographReposiory(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public async Task Update(PhotographEntity entity)
    {
        // update your entity here
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}


public class CachedPhotographRepository : IPhotograpRepository
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly IPhotograpRepository _repository;
    public CachedPhotographRepository(IPhotograpRepository repository, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cache));
        _repository = _repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }

    public async Task Update(PhotographEntity entity)
    {
        // do the update in the passed in repository
        await _repository.Update(entity);

        // if no exception is thrown, it was successful
        _cache.Remove(GetClientCacheKey(entityName, clientId));
    }
}
```

The catch is, the built-in DI/IoC container doesn't support decorator registrations, so you'll have to make it yourself via factory pattern or use a 3rd party IoC container which supports it.

```
services.AddScoped<IPhotograpRepository>(provider =>
    // Create an instance of PhotographRepository and inject the memory cache
    new CachedPhotographRepository(
        // create an instance of the repository and resolve the DbContext and pass to it
        new PhotographRepository(provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()),
        provider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>()
    )
);
```

It's per se not "bad" to use new within the composition root (where you configure your DI/IoC container), but with 3rd party IoC container its just more convenient.

Of course you can also register `PhotographRepository` with the IoC container and have it resolved. But that would also allow you to inject `PhotographRepository` into your services whereas the above prevents it, because only the `IPhotographRepository` interface is registered.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking but I wasn't too sure if it was good practice to use the IMemoryCache around my repository pattern, but it does make perfect sense to have it here.

Comment: Well that's correct. But for the simplicity of showing how to do it its good enough. In practice you may want to use [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and create an `PhotographRepository` and a `CachedPhotographRepository` (which injects `IPhotographRepository` or `PhotographRepository`) and wraps the calls. Just busy at work to write that big answer lol

Comment: That makes sense, The answer provided will not work in my scenario as I am using a generic repository to update the entity, so cannot wrap it in caching unfortunately, but the answer itself is really helpful thanks, when you are free is it possible to show me what you mean above as this is something I have not done before with a generic repository. Unless I create a new Update method in my Photograph repository that does not use the inherited one from my generic repository, but this is not ideal and may be confusing in the future?  Thanks!

Comment: Also added the decorator pattern, but keep in mind that it wasn't part of the original question and may be better suited for a new one next time