# How to load data into InMemory database on startup in Asp.Net Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I am working on Asp.Net Core 3.1 API. I have a few tables in the SQL Server database.

I am trying to use the InMemory database and I am trying to load the data into these tables on application startup.

I have written the below code.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
public MyContext ()
{
}

public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options)
    : base(options)
{

}

public virtual DbSet<TestEntity> TestEntity{ get; set; }
...
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("name=RuleDB");
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("myDbName"));
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "RuleDB": "Server=tcp:xyz.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30"
}
```

When I try to do `context.TestEntity.ToList();`, it shows no records.

I am basically trying to load the data from my SQL Server database to my InMemory database on application startup.

Am I missing any steps this is not a good approach ( I mean should I use InMemory Cache in place of InMemory database)?

Comment: If you are using entity framework code first you can create new migrations that are responsible for seeding data, you can call migrationBuilder.SQL("insert into table"); in the up method. then ensure the migration is applied on start up.

Comment: @DaveMorrison I am not using code first approach, it is database first

Comment: No worries i posted a solution i have used before... hope it helps you!

Comment: Why do you want to seed the inmemory database from the real database? The inmemory database is viewed as a Mock ideally used for unit tests, the information i provided is a means to seed the in memory database during start up routine, but if i have an understanding of what you are trying to achieve i may be able to help with the right solution.

Comment: @DaveMorrison this is my original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451674/inmemory-cache-vs-inmemory-database-vs-dictionary-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Why don't you have a repository layer that is responsible for fetching information from the db, it passes back a list of entities to a service, that service will depend on IMemoryCache.GetOrCreate, if there is no cached value for a particular cache key then you hit the repo to get results and cache, the only issue left is updating the records in cache.. 

i see 2 options... Items in IMemCache have short lifespan, so the calls to the repo occur frequently.

Or if your application is responsible for updates, implement IMemCache in repo and refresh after db is saved?

Comment: @DaveMorrison could you please provide the sample code?

Comment: Yes i will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

According to your code snippet, I didn't find where you add data to the in-memory database when the application starts up. So, I assume the issue is relate it.

Try to refer the following articles to Seed Data to The Database:

[Applying Seed Data To The Database](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding)

[Using EF Core's InMemory Provider To Store A "Database" In Memory](https://exceptionnotfound.net/ef-core-inmemory-asp-net-core-store-database/)

[Entity Framework Core InMemory Database](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-core-inmemory-database/)

Comment: in this way, I will have to write the same code for all the 100000 records in the entity? Is there any way to directly seed the whole database or at least on table level?

Answer (score -3):

In StartUp.cs, ConfigureServices make a reference to

```
services.AddTransient<IEntityRepository, EntityRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IEntityService, EntityService>();    
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Add a new repository interface.

```
public interface IEntityRepository
{
    Task<List<Entity>> GetEntity();
}
```

Add a new class that will encapsulate the DbContext, and implement the interface

```
public class EntityRepository : IEntityRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    
    public(EntityRepository dbContext){
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    public async Task<List<Entity>> GetEntity()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Entity.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Add another interface named IEntityService

```
public interface IEntityService
{
    Task<List<Entity>> GetEntity();
}
```

Add another class named EntityService, encapsulating the caching and repository calls.

```
public class EntityService : IEntityService
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    
    public(EntityService repository, IMemoryCache cache){
        _repository = repository;
        _cache = cache
    }
    
    public async Task<List<Entity>> GetEntity()
    {
        var cacheKey = $"{anything-can-be-user-specific-too}";

        return await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, x =>
        {
            var entities = _repository.GetEntity().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            x.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900);
            x.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

            return Task.FromResult(entities);
        });
    }
}
```

The cache policy that I have used as an example indicates that if the cache is not referenced in 10 minutes (slidingRefresh), it will expire and be removed. This can be used together with AbsoluteExpiration so that you can force the cache to be refreshed after let's say 1 hour...

Now make the IEntityService call your starting point, lets say you have a controller...

Inject the service to the controller e.g

```
 public class RandomController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IEntityService _entityService;

        public RandomController(IEntityService entityService)
        {
            _entityService = entityService;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("randomroute")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetEntities()
        {
            return Ok( await _entityService.GetEntity());
        }
    
    }
```

the first time executed the application will reference the database, however, all subsequent calls (until the cache policy has expired) will reference the memory cache.

Now if you want to change the cached item, you can introduce new services to perform database updates and then force a cache update by invalidating the cache key.

[Updating IMemoryCache once an entity has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743516/updating-imemorycache-once-an-entity-has-changed)

Comment: This solution is not working, you are trying to add records to an entity, this is not I am looking for